More than 10 detections per image when using efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32?
I have trained a model based on this colab: https://colab.research.google.com/github/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi/blob/master/Train_TFLite2_Object_Detction_Model.ipynb
It is detecting objects, but always seems to have only 10 detections when there are far more in the images I am using.
Is there a configuration which is limiting either the model or the way that the model is used?
I am using the following model and I have not changed any of the default configurations from what they are in the colab: efficientdet_d0_coco17_tpu-32
Any help appreciated!
